# isnull with AND : -An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, isnull

I am tryng to use  isnull with AND operator

```
SELECT * 
FROM   contacts AS cont 
       LEFT JOIN contactphones AS contPhone 
              ON cont.contactid = contPhone.contactid 
       LEFT JOIN sys_phonetypedesc AS phont 
              ON phont.typeid = contPhone.phonetype 
       LEFT JOIN salutations AS tsal 
              ON tsal.salutid = cont.salutation 
WHERE  cont.contactid = '29' 
       AND ( Isnull(phont.typedesc, 1) ) 
       AND ( Isnull(contPhone.phonenum, 1) ) 
ORDER  BY phont.typedesc
```

but got following error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition  is expected, near 'and'.

I also tried using the case statement

```
    SELECT    * 
FROM      contacts      AS cont 
LEFT JOIN contactphones AS contphone 
ON        cont.contactid = contphone.contactid 
LEFT JOIN sys_phonetypedesc AS phont 
ON        phont.typeid = contphone.phonetype 
LEFT JOIN salutations AS tsal 
ON        tsal.salutid = cont.salutation 
WHERE     cont.contactid = '29' 
AND       ( 
                    CASE 
                              WHEN phont.typedesc = NULL THEN 1 
                              ELSE phont.typedesc 
                    END as a)
```

but it is not working. I am looking for ifnull logic in MSSQL but case and if else not working correctly

please suggest

Comment: You are looking for `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL` not `ISNULL()`, SQL Server expect True/False there and your code won't return neither, unnless you add an operator =,>,<,>=,<=

Comment: You need to specify and Arithmetic Operator Condition in Where Clause, Your (isnull(phont.TypeDesc,1)) have something like (isnull(phont.TypeDesc,1)) <> 1 or the other case would be if you are checking for NULL condition then you should use IS NULL

Comment: You are trying to use where condition like select list and this will not work, you need to compare it with some values. Such as Isnull(phont.TypeDesc,1) <> 1 and like that based on your condition

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with the SQL? The right way to do it depends on what you expect/want to happen when one/both of those fields is null.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use `ISNULL()` here, instead you are looking for `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL`. First let's see why you get this error message

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'.

You get this error because `( Isnull(phont.typedesc, 1) )` is not a boolean expression and that what the `WHERE` clause needs (True or False).

eg: Let's assume `phont` IS NULL, then `ISNULL()` will return 1, so you are writing `cont.contactid = '29' AND 1 AND ...`.

- What should I do then to get ride of this error?

Just make it a boolean expression as `Isnull(phont.typedesc, 1) = 1` or what ever you want instead of `=1`, it maybe other too because it's not clear what you need to check.

Now, the use of `ISNULL()` as I seeis point less, cause the possible cases I can see is like the follow:

- `Isnull(phont.typedesc, 1) = 1` then directly `phont IS NULL`.
- `Isnull(phont.typedesc, 1) <> 1` then directly `phont IS NOT NULL`.
- `Isnull(phont.typedesc, 1) = AnyValue` then why not directly `phont = value` or `phont IN(<Values>)` if you are looking for more than 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

You're not comparing the result of isnull to anything in your where clause.

```
(isnull(phont.TypeDesc,1))
```

gives you either the TypeDesc, or if it's null gives you 1, but then you move directly onto an AND statement. In other words, if all relevant fields are null, what you'd be trying to do is:

```
where cont.ContactID = '29' and 1 and 1
```

You either have the isnull in the wrong place (if you want see it in your selected fields), or you forgot to compare it to something.

If you want to select rows where those fields are actually null then what you want is:

```
where cont.ContactID = '29' 
and phont.TypeDesc is null
and contPhone.PhoneNum is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from contacts as cont left join ContactPhones as contPhone on cont.ContactID=contPhone.ContactID 
left join SYS_PhoneTypeDesc as phont on 
phont.TypeID = contPhone.PhoneType 
left join SALUTATIONS as tsal on tsal.salutid = cont.Salutation where cont.ContactID = '29' and (isnull(phont.TypeDesc,1))=check what u want here  
and (isnull(contPhone.PhoneNum,1))=check what u want here enter code here
order by 
phont.TypeDesc
```

Answer (score 0):

`Isnull(contPhone.phonenum,1)` return 1 when your `contPhone.phonenum` value will be null else it will return that column value but the point is you got error because  you have not used any comparison value as a result it thrown error 
     Your condition will be like below

```
          Where contactId=29 and isnull(phonenum,1)= // any value
```

Comment: What's the point from `isnull(phonenum,1)= value`, if value is 1 then why not just `phonenum IS NULL`, if value is not 1 then why not just `phonenum IS NOT NULL` or `phonenum = value`? So the `ISNULL()` is pointless here